# Implemented JWT : Not able to authenticate : Spring security

Tags: spring, spring-boot, spring-security, jwt, microservices

I am trying to create a bank application using spring security.
And I have implemented JWT.
But after adding JWT filter I am not able to authenticate.
I am using spring security default login page and custom authentication provider.
Please let me know what I am doing wrong that I am not able to login

I tried to put breakpoint on jwtValidator Filter, both of the filters are getting injected in filter chain.

SecurityConfig

```
    @Configuration
     public class SecurityConfig {
    @Bean
    SecurityFilterChain defaultSecurityFilterChain(HttpSecurity http) throws Exception
    {
           CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler requestHandler = new        

CsrfTokenRequestAttributeHandler();
           requestHandler.setCsrfRequestAttributeName("_csrf");
            
http.sessionManagement(session -> session.sessionCreationPolicy(SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS))
       .cors(corsCustomizer -> corsCustomizer.configurationSource(
           new CorsConfigurationSource() {
                 @Override
       public CorsConfiguration getCorsConfiguration(HttpServletRequest request) {
                CorsConfiguration config = new CorsConfiguration();
                config.setAllowedOrigins(Collections.singletonList("http://localhost:4200"));
                config.setAllowedMethods(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.setAllowCredentials(true);
                config.setAllowedHeaders(Collections.singletonList("*"));
                config.setExposedHeaders(Arrays.asList("Authorization"));
                config.setMaxAge(3600L);
                return config;
              }
          }))
           .csrf(csrf -> csrf.disable())
           .addFilterBefore(new JWTTokenValidatorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
           .addFilterBefore(new RequestValidationBeforeFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class) 
           .addFilterAfter(new LoggingAfterFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
           .addFilterAfter(new JWTTokenGeneratorFilter(), BasicAuthenticationFilter.class)
           .authorizeHttpRequests()
           .requestMatchers("/myAccount").hasAuthority("VIEWACCOUNT")           
           .requestMatchers("/myBalance").hasAnyAuthority("VIEWBAL", "ViewBal")  
           .requestMatchers("/customerList").hasRole("USER")
           .requestMatchers("/myCards").authenticated()                          
           .requestMatchers("/contactUs", "/register").permitAll()            
           .and().formLogin(withDefaults()).httpBasic(withDefaults());
        
        return http.build();
    }

    @Bean
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder() { return new BCryptPasswordEncoder(); }
     
}
```

Login Controller

```
    
@RestController
public class LoginController {
    
    @Autowired
    CustomerRepo customerRepo;
    @Autowired
    PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;
    
    /*
     * here we are registering user by BCryptPasswordEncoder (password encoder)
     */
    @PostMapping("/register")
    public ResponseEntity<String> registerUser(@RequestBody Customer customer)
    {
        Customer savedCustomer =  null;
        ResponseEntity<String> response = null;
        try
        {
            System.out.println(customer);
            String hashPwd = passwordEncoder.encode(customer.getPassword());
            customer.setPassword(hashPwd);
            savedCustomer = customerRepo.save(customer); // here we are saving user in db
            if(savedCustomer.getId() > 0)
            {
                response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.CREATED)
                         .body("User created successfully !!");
            }
        }
        catch(Exception ex)
        {
            response = ResponseEntity.status(HttpStatus.INTERNAL_SERVER_ERROR)
                                     .body("An exception occured due to " + ex.getMessage());
        }
        return response;
    }
    
    @GetMapping("/customerList")
    public Iterable<Customer> customerList()
    {
        Iterable<Customer> list = customerRepo.findAll();
        return list;
    }
    
    @RequestMapping("/user")
    public Customer getUserDetailsAfterLogin(Authentication authentication) {
        List<Customer> customers = customerRepo.findByEmail(authentication.getName());
        if (customers.size() > 0) {
            return customers.get(0);
        } else {
            return null;
        }

    }
}
```

Authentication Provider

```
package com.example.demo.service;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.List;
import java.util.Set;

import org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.AuthenticationProvider;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.AuthenticationException;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.SimpleGrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.crypto.password.PasswordEncoder;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Component;
import org.springframework.stereotype.Service;

import com.example.demo.model.Authority;
import com.example.demo.model.Customer;
import com.example.demo.repo.CustomerRepo;

@Service
public class CustomAuthenticationProvider implements AuthenticationProvider
{


    @Autowired
    private CustomerRepo customerRepository;

    @Autowired
    private PasswordEncoder passwordEncoder;

    @Override
    public Authentication authenticate(Authentication authentication) throws AuthenticationException {
        String username = authentication.getName();
        String pwd = authentication.getCredentials().toString();
        List<Customer> customer = customerRepository.findByEmail(username);
        if (customer.size() > 0) {
            if (passwordEncoder.matches(pwd, customer.get(0).getPassword())) {
                return new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, pwd, getGrantedAuthorities(customer.get(0).getAuthorities()));
            } else {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid password!");
            }
        }else {
            throw new BadCredentialsException("No user registered with this details!");
        }
    }

    private List<GrantedAuthority> getGrantedAuthorities(Set<Authority> authorities) {
        List<GrantedAuthority> grantedAuthorities = new ArrayList<>();
        for(Authority auth : authorities)
               grantedAuthorities.add(new SimpleGrantedAuthority(auth.getName()));
            
        return grantedAuthorities;
    }
    
    @Override
    public boolean supports(Class<?> authentication) {
        return (UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken.class.isAssignableFrom(authentication));
    }

}
```

JWTTokenGenerator

```
package com.example.demo.filter;

import com.example.demo.constants.SecurityConstants;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.GrantedAuthority;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;
import java.util.Collection;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashSet;
import java.util.Set;

public class JWTTokenGeneratorFilter extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        Authentication authentication = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
        if (null != authentication) {
            SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));
            String jwt = Jwts.builder().setIssuer("Eazy Bank").setSubject("JWT Token")
                    .claim("username", authentication.getName())
                    .claim("authorities", populateAuthorities(authentication.getAuthorities()))
                    .setIssuedAt(new Date())
                    .setExpiration(new Date((new Date()).getTime() + 30000000))
                    .signWith(key).compact();
            response.setHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER, jwt);
        }

        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return !request.getServletPath().equals("/user");
    }

    private String populateAuthorities(Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> collection) {
        Set<String> authoritiesSet = new HashSet<>();
        for (GrantedAuthority authority : collection) {
            authoritiesSet.add(authority.getAuthority());
        }
        return String.join(",", authoritiesSet);
    }

}
```

JWT Token Validator

```
package com.example.demo.filter;

import com.example.demo.constants.SecurityConstants;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Claims;
import io.jsonwebtoken.Jwts;
import io.jsonwebtoken.security.Keys;
import jakarta.servlet.FilterChain;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.BadCredentialsException;
import org.springframework.security.authentication.UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken;
import org.springframework.security.core.Authentication;
import org.springframework.security.core.authority.AuthorityUtils;
import org.springframework.security.core.context.SecurityContextHolder;
import org.springframework.web.filter.OncePerRequestFilter;

import javax.crypto.SecretKey;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.nio.charset.StandardCharsets;

public class JWTTokenValidatorFilter  extends OncePerRequestFilter {

    @Override
    protected void doFilterInternal(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response, FilterChain filterChain)
            throws ServletException, IOException {
        String jwt = request.getHeader(SecurityConstants.JWT_HEADER);
        if (null != jwt) {
            try {
                SecretKey key = Keys.hmacShaKeyFor(
                        SecurityConstants.JWT_KEY.getBytes(StandardCharsets.UTF_8));

                Claims claims = Jwts.parserBuilder()
                        .setSigningKey(key)
                        .build()
                        .parseClaimsJws(jwt)
                        .getBody();
                String username = String.valueOf(claims.get("username"));
                String authorities = (String) claims.get("authorities");
                Authentication auth = new UsernamePasswordAuthenticationToken(username, null,
                        AuthorityUtils.commaSeparatedStringToAuthorityList(authorities));
                SecurityContextHolder.getContext().setAuthentication(auth);
            } catch (Exception e) {
                throw new BadCredentialsException("Invalid Token received!");
            }

        }
        filterChain.doFilter(request, response);
    }

    @Override
    protected boolean shouldNotFilter(HttpServletRequest request) {
        return request.getServletPath().equals("/user");
    }

}
```

I tried to login into my bank application after implementing jwt but I am not able to authenticate, it always redirects me back to login page.

Comment: Handing out JWTs to browsers is not recommended as there are multiple security issues with this approach. There is no such implementation in spring security because of these reasons, so why are you building a custom security security solution that has built in security issues, and not actually reading the spring security docs?

Answer (score 1):

This problem has nothing to do with your JWT implementation, but because you're combining a form login (`.formLogin()`) with a stateless session (`SessionCreationPolicy.STATELESS`), which is contradictory.

When you use a login form, you want to login only once. The way this works is that Spring stores your session state upon authentication, and sends you a `JSESSIONID` cookie which the webbrowser automatically sends back for all subsequent requests. With that cookie, Spring can then identify you and restore your session state.

However, since you configured sessions to be stateless, Spring discards its session state after each request. So basically your `JSESSIONID` is no longer recognized.

To solve this, you have to remove either the form login or the stateless session policy. In your case, it makes more sense to remove Spring's form login because you're building a JWT-authentication mechanism in stead and your goal is to essentially restore your session based on your JWT token.

Comment: How can I remove spring form login, do I need to make my own login endpoint with custom logic? I am following a tutorial in which angular is used so formLogin is being used witth JWT. Please help me here.

Comment: But I am not implementing UI part, so maybe my configurations are wrong here.

Comment: @Tara From your code I see two options **(1)** You develop a custom UI in Angular that sends the username + password as basic authentication headers and you store the JWT somewhere in the frontend. **(2)** You remove the stateless session from your Spring security and then you can the Spring Security form login as normal. But in this case, you completely make the JWT mechanism obsolete.